# Adding reg exp in javascript to determine if url has any character after /

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, url, any

I'd like to add a regex to determine if a url contains any character after the "/" in the url. Right now this regex is just looking for "a". I can't seem to get any concatenation of regular expressions to work.

```
$(function() {
    if ( document.location.href.indexOf('services/a') > -1 ) {
      $(window).scrollTop(450)
    }
});
```

Comment: Give an example. Did you mean `(?<=\/).`

Comment: What does the full URL look like? http://www.yoursite.com/services/a ?

Comment: I used to asked regex question myself until I discovered [this](http://regex101.com/) site. Makes creating your own regex a lot easier. ;-)

Comment: Your question mentiones regexes, but I don't see a regex in your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
var b = /services\/./.test( document.location.href );

if (b)
   alert("there is a character after services/");
```

Comment: That worked perfectly thanks!
working code:
$(function() {
    var b = /services\/./.test( document.location.href );
    if (b) {
        console.log("yes");
      $(window).scrollTop(450)
    }
});

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  if (!document.location.href.match(/\/$/) { // $ matches only if the preceding character is the end of the string
    <your code here>
  }
});
```

should work.

Comment: Not sure this will work. For example `http://www.example.com/services/` will match too.